# Api web service does not run after updating data in AngularJS

Tags: arrays, angularjs, web-services

I have two functions in my controller. init () running when initializing the controller, add_rule () running in the click event of a button. In the first case, the function return a data with which I fill an array. With the contents of the array, drawing an accordion bootstrap. This is my function:

```
function init() {
            allocationService.getrules().then(
                function (data) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        var rule = {
                            RuleName: data[i].ruleName,
                            RuleId: data[i].ruleid,
                            IsActive: data[i].isActive
                        };
                        $scope.listRules.push(rule);
                    }

                    loadfarmbyrule();
                }, function (error) {
                    toastr.error("Ha ocurrido listando las reglas", "Error", vm.toastrOptions);
                }),
}
```

The problem comes when I run the second function:

```
  function add_rule() {
            if (validateData() === false) {
                return;
            }          
            var flag = true;
            var today = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
            allocationService.saverule(vm.getrule, true, today, today).then(
                function (data) {
                    toastr.info("Regla agregada correctamente", "Exito", vm.toastrOptions);

                    $scope.listRules = [];
                    $scope.init = init();
                },
                function (error) {
                    flag = false;
                    console.log(error)
                    toastr.error("Ha ocurrido agregando la regla", "Error", vm.toastrOptions);
                }
            )
        }
```

When the sucess happens in my service that adds a new rule, I call the function init () again to load the array new data from the database, but this is not happening, because if I put a breakpoint the method on the Web Api, not going up there and therefore still shows the array with the initial data, not consuming the service again and therefore does not refresh the data.

Thank you for the help that you may be able to provide.

Greetings.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: `$scope.init = init();` does not call the `init()` function, it simply assigns it as a function on `$scope`.

Comment: Ok, how could initialize the scope again. Because if I reload the page, the method in the api runs perfectly and brings the updated data. What does not happen if I run the add_rule function.

Comment: Just call `init();`.